# ASP simple gridview with paging

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

In my aspx I have:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
    AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="True">
</asp:GridView>
```

I have a  very simple class:

```
class ItemTable
{
    public ItemTable(string mc, string dt)
    {
        this.Machinecode = mc;
        this.Datetime = dt;
    }
    string Machinecode { get; set; }
    string Datetime { get; set; }
}
```

And in my code I have:

```
List<ItemTable> infos = new List<ItemTable>(); 
//Some code for add item in infos...
GridView1.DataSource = infos;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

But i have this error:

> The data source for GridView with id 'GridView1' did not have any properties or attributes from which to generate columns.  Ensure that your data source has content.

How do I fix this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your properties to `public` like this

```
class ItemTable
{
    public ItemTable(string mc, string dt)
    {
        this.Machinecode = mc;
        this.Datetime = dt;
    }
    public string Machinecode { get; set; }
    public string Datetime { get; set; }
}
```

When no access-specifier is mentioned, `private` is taken as access-specifier.